# Dapper stops mapping DateTime values with Multi-Mapping

Tags: .net, dapper

Ran into a weird issue where `DateTime` values from a Sql Server DB map just fine with a simple query, but if I introduce multi-mapping it stops working.  By stops working, I mean if the .NET property is a `DateTime` it will be `default` and if it's a `DateTime?` type, it will be null.

I played with my code and this will work:

```
IEnumerable<TReturnModel> modelList = await SqlMapper.QueryAsync<TReturnModel>(
                conn,
                sql: command.CommandText,
                //map: (Func<object[], TReturnModel>)((objs) =>
                //{
                //    var model = objs[0] as TReturnModel;

                //    if (model != null)
                //    {
                //        var modelHash = CheckSumHelper.CreateCheckSum(model);

                //        if (objTracking.ContainsKey(modelHash))
                //        {
                //            objs[0] = objTracking[modelHash];
                //        }
                //        else
                //        {
                //            objTracking.Add(modelHash, model);
                //        }
                //    }

                //    return command.HandleSplitMapping(objs) as TReturnModel;
                //}),
                //types: command.GetType().GetGenericArguments(),
                //splitOn: string.Join(',', command.GetDataSplitters()),
                param: command.Parameters);
```

But this will not:

```
IEnumerable<TReturnModel> modelList = await SqlMapper.QueryAsync<TReturnModel>(
                conn,
                sql: command.CommandText,
                map: (Func<object[], TReturnModel>)((objs) =>
                {
                    var model = objs[0] as TReturnModel;

                    if (model != null)
                    {
                        var modelHash = CheckSumHelper.CreateCheckSum(model);

                        if (objTracking.ContainsKey(modelHash))
                        {
                            objs[0] = objTracking[modelHash];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objTracking.Add(modelHash, model);
                        }
                    }

                    return command.HandleSplitMapping(objs) as TReturnModel;
                }),
                types: command.GetType().GetGenericArguments(),
                splitOn: string.Join(',', command.GetDataSplitters()),
                param: command.Parameters);
```

I left the removed code commented to demonstrate the only difference is the multi-mapping parameters being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are (seemingly unwritten as I can't find anything online) rules pertaining to the SQL statement that I found when trying to figure this out:

1. The column(s) you specify to split upon cannot be the first column(s) in the SELECT statement
2. Any columns listed AFTER your split column(s) will not be mapped

Simply moving my `DateTime` column above the split column(s) in my SELECT statement resolved the issue.